# Using php to return all results greater that a certain ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check my database and return any new additions to the DB.

My client can pass in the ID of the last item it received from the DB. So i think that would be a good starting place.

So is it the case that I set the offset to the ID(theid) i pass in as an argument to the php script and that will only return Database entries newer than that id? Or am i barking up the wrong tree altogether?

Here is what I mean with code

```
$theid  = isset($_GET['theid']) ? $_GET['theid'] : "";
$type   = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : "global";
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : theid;
$count  = isset($_GET['count']) ? $_GET['count'] : "100";
$sort   = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : "id ASC";

// Localize the GET variables
$udid  = isset($_GET['udid']) ? $_GET['udid'] : "";
$name  = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name']  : "";
$clubname  = isset($_GET['clubname']) ? $_GET['clubname']  : "";

// Protect against sql injections
$type   = mysql_real_escape_string($type);
$offset = mysql_real_escape_string($offset);
$count  = mysql_real_escape_string($count);
$sort   = mysql_real_escape_string($sort);
$udid   = mysql_real_escape_string($udid);
$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$clubname   = mysql_real_escape_string($clubname);

// Build the sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";

switch($type) {
    case "global":
        $sql .= "1 ";
        break;
    case "device":
        $sql .= "udid = '$udid' ";
        break;
    case "name":
        $sql .= "name = '$name' ";
        break;
    case "clubname":
        $sql .= "clubname = '$clubname' ";
        break;
}

$sql .= "ORDER BY $sort ";
$sql .= "LIMIT $offset,$count ";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

if(!$result) {
    die("Error retrieving scores " . mysql_error());
}
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the ID is a sequenced number, and newer entries will ALWAYS have a higher ID than the previous, you want the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > $id;
```

Otherwise, you need to add a timestamp to your tables, and run two queries:

SELECT createdAt FROM table WHERE id = $id;

Assign that value to $timestamp and then run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE createdAt > $timestamp
```

Optionally, you could combine the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE createdAt > (SELECT createdAt FROM table WHERE id = $id)
```

Using the offset is a bad idea.  If any records prior to your ID are deleted, your results will be inaccurate.  For example, lets say the following happens:

- Insert 100 records (last ID is 100)
- Delete records 47 and 48
- Add 1 record ( last ID is 101 )
- Find records new since id #100

If you use an offset of 100, you will have no records returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the last inserted id using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` build-in function.

```
SELECT @Last_id:= LAST_INSERT_id();
#now wait a while and let other inserts happen, then...
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > @Last_id;
```

However `LAST_INSERT_ID() will only give you the last inserted id **in your own connection!**.
If you have multiple connections, due to having multiple web-servers querying one database, you might get unexpected results.

To get the real last inserted ID **when you have multiple connections** you'd need to add a trigger to your table.
Or only insert using some stored procedure that keeps global track of the inserted id.
Or **(recommended)** use timestamps in your table, so you can see when a row was created.

If you add a TIMESTAMP field to your table, you can do a

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE create_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

To field all rows that have been added in the last 15 minutes.

If you want to keep a log of all inserts and such, you have to add a trigger.
This log will fill up fast though...

Using a trigger:
Create a logging table like so:

```
Table Insert_log
  id: autoincrement primary key
  tablename: varchar not null
  insert_time: timestamp
  insert_id: integer
```

and add a trigger for **every** table that you want to keep track of in the insert log.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_table1_each AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Insert_log (tablename, insert_id) VALUES ('table1', new.id);
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: But doesn't that just show the last id? Same a just selecting the LAST_INSERT_ID() directly?

Comment: Not if you store the last_insert_id and **then** select all rows with id's > stored_last_insert_id.

Comment: Alright, judging from your code you used the last_insert_id straight away after getting, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

add this above $sql .= "ORDER BY $sort "

```
$sql .= "WHERE id > $theid ";
```